# How to count the number of rows returned when using a Data View Web Part XSLT and Xpath

Tags: data-view-web-part, xslt, xpath

I have created a data source to link, via a join, 2 lists in sharepoint 2010. The result is a Data View Web Part. I would like to count the results returned in the second 'lookup' list. So for example, list one's title is "Events" and the second list is "Attendees". I want to count how many attendees there are to a specific event. My DVWP is correctly pulling back data.

Event 1 has 2 attendees
Event 2 has 1 attendee
Event 3 has 1 attendee

My current xpath looks like this:

count(../../../signup-attendees/Rows/Row[../../../signup-attendees/Rows/Row/@Signup_ID_Lookup=@ID]) which returns 3; 3; 3;

I've also tried:

count(../../../signup-attendees/Rows/Row[../../../signup-attendees/Rows/Row/@Signup_ID_Lookup=current()/@ID]) which returns 4; 4; 4;

Does anyone have any ideas how I can return 2; 1; 1;?

***UPDATE***

```
            <dsQueryResponse>
  <signup-attendees>
    <Rows>
      <Row ContentTypeId="0x0100D1FB1F346446184B9F97702C63D76495" Title="Signup 01" _ModerationComments="" File_x0020_Type="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapall="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapico="" Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup="<a onclick="OpenPopUpPage('https://sub.mydomain.co.uk/sites/heg/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={65E8D46B-74CB-4917-A11E-4838CB62684D}&ID=2&RootFolder=*', RefreshPage); return false;" href="https://sub.mydomain.co.uk/sites/heg/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={65E8D46B-74CB-4917-A11E-4838CB62684D}&ID=2&RootFolder=*">Test 02</a>" Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup.="2;#Test 02" Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup_x00="2" Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup_x000="Test 02" ID="1" ContentType="Item" Modified="5/28/2012 12:04 PM" Created="5/28/2012 11:54 AM" Author="<span class="ms-imnSpan"><img border='0' height='12' width='12' class='ms-imnImg' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='' /><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=23">MYDOMAIN\Astudent</a></span>" Author.id="23" Author.title="MYDOMAIN\Astudent" Author.span="<nobr><span><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=23">MYDOMAIN\Astudent</a><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/><img border='0' height='12' width='12' class='ms-imnImg' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='' /></span></nobr>" Editor="<span class="ms-imnSpan"><img border='0' height='12' width='12' class='ms-imnImg' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='' /><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=23">MYDOMAIN\Astudent</a></span>" Editor.id="23" Editor.title="MYDOMAIN\Astudent" Editor.span="<nobr><span><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=23">MYDOMAIN\Astudent</a><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/><img border='0' height='12' width='12' class='ms-imnImg' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='' /></span></nobr>" _HasCopyDestinations="" _HasCopyDestinations.value="" _CopySource="" owshiddenversion="2" owshiddenversion.="2" WorkflowVersion="1" WorkflowVersion.="1" _UIVersion="512" _UIVersion.="512" _UIVersionString="1.0" Attachments="0" _ModerationStatus="Approved" _ModerationStatus.="0" LinkTitleNoMenu="Signup 01" LinkTitle="Signup 01" LinkTitle2="Signup 01" SelectTitle="1" InstanceID="" InstanceID.="" Order="100" Order.="100.000000000000" GUID="{5968E86D-B7DD-444D-BA18-37C407BE9D7C}" WorkflowInstanceID="" FileRef="/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees/1_.000" FileRef.urlencode="%2Fsites%2Fheg%2FLists%2Fsignupattendees%2F1%5F%2E000" FileRef.urlencodeasurl="/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees/1_.000" FileDirRef="/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees" Last_x0020_Modified="5/28/2012 11:54 AM" Created_x0020_Date="0;#2012-05-28 11:54:50" Created_x0020_Date.ifnew="" FSObjType="0" SortBehavior="0" PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" FileLeafRef="1_.000" FileLeafRef.Name="1_" FileLeafRef.Suffix="000" UniqueId="{47ECB1FB-1EC8-4E40-B669-7AE9263DFC50}" SyncClientId="" ProgId="" ScopeId="{F73AF7C0-59A1-4A38-A1FF-D6600650485E}" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type="" _EditMenuTableStart="1_.000" _EditMenuTableStart2="1" _EditMenuTableEnd="1" LinkFilenameNoMenu="1_.000" LinkFilename="1_.000" LinkFilename2="1_.000" DocIcon="" ServerUrl="/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees/1_.000" EncodedAbsUrl="https://sub.mydomain.co.uk/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees/1_.000" BaseName="1_" MetaInfo="" MetaInfo.="1;#" _Level="1" _Level.="1" _IsCurrentVersion="Yes" _IsCurrentVersion.value="1" ItemChildCount="0" FolderChildCount="0"></Row>
      <Row ContentTypeId="0x0100D1FB1F346446184B9F97702C63D76495" Title="Signup 03" _ModerationComments="" File_x0020_Type="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapall="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapico="" Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup="<a onclick="OpenPopUpPage('https://sub.mydomain.co.uk/sites/heg/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={65E8D46B-74CB-4917-A11E-4838CB62684D}&ID=1&RootFolder=*', RefreshPage); return false;" href="https://sub.mydomain.co.uk/sites/heg/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={65E8D46B-74CB-4917-A11E-4838CB62684D}&ID=1&RootFolder=*">Test 01</a>" Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup.="1;#Test 01" Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup_x00="1" Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup_x000="Test 01" ID="3" ContentType="Item" Modified="5/28/2012 12:11 PM" Created="5/28/2012 11:55 AM" Author="<span class="ms-imnSpan"><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_9,type=smtp'/></a><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a></span>" Author.id="16" Author.title="Jane Doe" Author.span="<nobr><span><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_10,type=smtp'/></a></span></nobr>" Editor="<span class="ms-imnSpan"><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_11,type=smtp'/></a><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a></span>" Editor.id="16" Editor.title="Jane Doe" Editor.span="<nobr><span><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_12,type=smtp'/></a></span></nobr>" _HasCopyDestinations="" _HasCopyDestinations.value="" _CopySource="" owshiddenversion="2" owshiddenversion.="2" WorkflowVersion="1" WorkflowVersion.="1" _UIVersion="512" _UIVersion.="512" _UIVersionString="1.0" Attachments="0" _ModerationStatus="Approved" _ModerationStatus.="0" LinkTitleNoMenu="Signup 03" LinkTitle="Signup 03" LinkTitle2="Signup 03" SelectTitle="3" InstanceID="" InstanceID.="" Order="300" Order.="300.000000000000" GUID="{1BB3705E-0A47-475F-BED5-9B869A7699F3}" WorkflowInstanceID="" FileRef="/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees/3_.000" FileRef.urlencode="%2Fsites%2Fheg%2FLists%2Fsignupattendees%2F3%5F%2E000" FileRef.urlencodeasurl="/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees/3_.000" FileDirRef="/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees" Last_x0020_Modified="5/28/2012 11:55 AM" Created_x0020_Date="0;#2012-05-28 11:55:15" Created_x0020_Date.ifnew="" FSObjType="0" SortBehavior="0" PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" FileLeafRef="3_.000" FileLeafRef.Name="3_" FileLeafRef.Suffix="000" UniqueId="{B49A4785-671C-45F8-A74C-0702D93B01E8}" SyncClientId="" ProgId="" ScopeId="{F73AF7C0-59A1-4A38-A1FF-D6600650485E}" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type="" _EditMenuTableStart="3_.000" _EditMenuTableStart2="3" _EditMenuTableEnd="3" LinkFilenameNoMenu="3_.000" LinkFilename="3_.000" LinkFilename2="3_.000" DocIcon="" ServerUrl="/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees/3_.000" EncodedAbsUrl="https://sub.mydomain.co.uk/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees/3_.000" BaseName="3_" MetaInfo="" MetaInfo.="3;#" _Level="1" _Level.="1" _IsCurrentVersion="Yes" _IsCurrentVersion.value="1" ItemChildCount="0" FolderChildCount="0"></Row>
      <Row ContentTypeId="0x0100D1FB1F346446184B9F97702C63D76495" Title="Signup 04" _ModerationComments="" File_x0020_Type="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapall="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapico="" Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup="<a onclick="OpenPopUpPage('https://sub.mydomain.co.uk/sites/heg/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={65E8D46B-74CB-4917-A11E-4838CB62684D}&ID=1&RootFolder=*', RefreshPage); return false;" href="https://sub.mydomain.co.uk/sites/heg/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={65E8D46B-74CB-4917-A11E-4838CB62684D}&ID=1&RootFolder=*">Test 01</a>" Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup.="1;#Test 01" Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup_x00="1" Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup_x000="Test 01" ID="4" ContentType="Item" Modified="5/28/2012 12:12 PM" Created="5/28/2012 12:09 PM" Author="<span class="ms-imnSpan"><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_13,type=smtp'/></a><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a></span>" Author.id="16" Author.title="Jane Doe" Author.span="<nobr><span><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_14,type=smtp'/></a></span></nobr>" Editor="<span class="ms-imnSpan"><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_15,type=smtp'/></a><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a></span>" Editor.id="16" Editor.title="Jane Doe" Editor.span="<nobr><span><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_16,type=smtp'/></a></span></nobr>" _HasCopyDestinations="" _HasCopyDestinations.value="" _CopySource="" owshiddenversion="2" owshiddenversion.="2" WorkflowVersion="1" WorkflowVersion.="1" _UIVersion="512" _UIVersion.="512" _UIVersionString="1.0" Attachments="0" _ModerationStatus="Approved" _ModerationStatus.="0" LinkTitleNoMenu="Signup 04" LinkTitle="Signup 04" LinkTitle2="Signup 04" SelectTitle="4" InstanceID="" InstanceID.="" Order="400" Order.="400.000000000000" GUID="{24B16CDB-A943-49B8-A309-0D674ABB47D1}" WorkflowInstanceID="" FileRef="/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees/4_.000" FileRef.urlencode="%2Fsites%2Fheg%2FLists%2Fsignupattendees%2F4%5F%2E000" FileRef.urlencodeasurl="/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees/4_.000" FileDirRef="/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees" Last_x0020_Modified="5/28/2012 12:09 PM" Created_x0020_Date="0;#2012-05-28 12:09:26" Created_x0020_Date.ifnew="" FSObjType="0" SortBehavior="0" PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" FileLeafRef="4_.000" FileLeafRef.Name="4_" FileLeafRef.Suffix="000" UniqueId="{DD1D8DAC-072D-435B-9E5A-6A9B24B52D87}" SyncClientId="" ProgId="" ScopeId="{F73AF7C0-59A1-4A38-A1FF-D6600650485E}" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type="" _EditMenuTableStart="4_.000" _EditMenuTableStart2="4" _EditMenuTableEnd="4" LinkFilenameNoMenu="4_.000" LinkFilename="4_.000" LinkFilename2="4_.000" DocIcon="" ServerUrl="/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees/4_.000" EncodedAbsUrl="https://sub.mydomain.co.uk/sites/heg/Lists/signupattendees/4_.000" BaseName="4_" MetaInfo="" MetaInfo.="4;#" _Level="1" _Level.="1" _IsCurrentVersion="Yes" _IsCurrentVersion.value="1" ItemChildCount="0" FolderChildCount="0"></Row>
    </Rows>
  </signup-attendees>
  <signup-list>
    <Rows>
      <Row ContentTypeId="0x010065D6ABB14ACC8841AF4B3B24773A8454" Title="Test 01" _ModerationComments="" File_x0020_Type="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapall="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapico="" KpiDescription="Test 01" StartDate="5/31/2012" Lead="<span class="ms-imnSpan"><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a></span>" Lead.id="16" Lead.title="Jane Doe" Lead.span="<nobr><span><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/></span></nobr>" Location="Babbage 301" Max_x0020_no_x0020_people="100" Max_x0020_no_x0020_people.="100.000000000000" Max_x0020_no_x0020_reserves="5" Max_x0020_no_x0020_reserves.="5.00000000000000" ID="1" ContentType="Item" Modified="5/28/2012 12:36 PM" Created="5/28/2012 11:14 AM" Author="<span class="ms-imnSpan"><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_17,type=smtp'/></a><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a></span>" Author.id="16" Author.title="Jane Doe" Author.span="<nobr><span><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_18,type=smtp'/></a></span></nobr>" Editor="<span class="ms-imnSpan"><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_19,type=smtp'/></a><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a></span>" Editor.id="16" Editor.title="Jane Doe" Editor.span="<nobr><span><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_20,type=smtp'/></a></span></nobr>" _HasCopyDestinations="" _HasCopyDestinations.value="" _CopySource="" owshiddenversion="2" owshiddenversion.="2" WorkflowVersion="1" WorkflowVersion.="1" _UIVersion="512" _UIVersion.="512" _UIVersionString="1.0" Attachments="0" _ModerationStatus="Approved" _ModerationStatus.="0" LinkTitleNoMenu="Test 01" LinkTitle="Test 01" LinkTitle2="Test 01" SelectTitle="1" InstanceID="" InstanceID.="" Order="100" Order.="100.000000000000" GUID="{50770C6D-A7B0-48F3-AA35-91A576803FF6}" WorkflowInstanceID="" FileRef="/sites/heg/Lists/signup/1_.000" FileRef.urlencode="%2Fsites%2Fheg%2FLists%2Fsignup%2F1%5F%2E000" FileRef.urlencodeasurl="/sites/heg/Lists/signup/1_.000" FileDirRef="/sites/heg/Lists/signup" Last_x0020_Modified="5/28/2012 11:14 AM" Created_x0020_Date="0;#2012-05-28 11:14:58" Created_x0020_Date.ifnew="" FSObjType="0" SortBehavior="0" PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" FileLeafRef="1_.000" FileLeafRef.Name="1_" FileLeafRef.Suffix="000" UniqueId="{123F06E6-C7C9-455B-BA98-5A818FCF95D4}" SyncClientId="" ProgId="" ScopeId="{F73AF7C0-59A1-4A38-A1FF-D6600650485E}" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type="" _EditMenuTableStart="1_.000" _EditMenuTableStart2="1" _EditMenuTableEnd="1" LinkFilenameNoMenu="1_.000" LinkFilename="1_.000" LinkFilename2="1_.000" DocIcon="" ServerUrl="/sites/heg/Lists/signup/1_.000" EncodedAbsUrl="https://sub.mydomain.co.uk/sites/heg/Lists/signup/1_.000" BaseName="1_" MetaInfo="" MetaInfo.="1;#" _Level="1" _Level.="1" _IsCurrentVersion="Yes" _IsCurrentVersion.value="1" ItemChildCount="0" FolderChildCount="0"></Row>
      <Row ContentTypeId="0x010065D6ABB14ACC8841AF4B3B24773A8454" Title="Test 02" _ModerationComments="" File_x0020_Type="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapall="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon="" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapico="" KpiDescription="Test 02" StartDate="6/2/2012" Lead="<span class="ms-imnSpan"><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=15">John Doe</a></span>" Lead.id="15" Lead.title="John Doe" Lead.span="<nobr><span><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=15">John Doe</a><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/></span></nobr>" Location="PSQ 508" Max_x0020_no_x0020_people="" Max_x0020_no_x0020_people.="" Max_x0020_no_x0020_reserves="" Max_x0020_no_x0020_reserves.="" ID="2" ContentType="Item" Modified="5/28/2012 12:37 PM" Created="5/28/2012 11:15 AM" Author="<span class="ms-imnSpan"><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_21,type=smtp'/></a><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a></span>" Author.id="16" Author.title="Jane Doe" Author.span="<nobr><span><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_22,type=smtp'/></a></span></nobr>" Editor="<span class="ms-imnSpan"><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_23,type=smtp'/></a><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a></span>" Editor.id="16" Editor.title="Jane Doe" Editor.span="<nobr><span><a onClick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/sites/heg/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=16">Jane Doe</a><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/><a href='javascript:;' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' class='ms-imnImg' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='Jane.Doe@email.co.uk' id='imn_24,type=smtp'/></a></span></nobr>" _HasCopyDestinations="" _HasCopyDestinations.value="" _CopySource="" owshiddenversion="3" owshiddenversion.="3" WorkflowVersion="1" WorkflowVersion.="1" _UIVersion="512" _UIVersion.="512" _UIVersionString="1.0" Attachments="0" _ModerationStatus="Approved" _ModerationStatus.="0" LinkTitleNoMenu="Test 02" LinkTitle="Test 02" LinkTitle2="Test 02" SelectTitle="2" InstanceID="" InstanceID.="" Order="200" Order.="200.000000000000" GUID="{374C1FC9-C4B2-4EC0-85DD-7D18114462D2}" WorkflowInstanceID="" FileRef="/sites/heg/Lists/signup/2_.000" FileRef.urlencode="%2Fsites%2Fheg%2FLists%2Fsignup%2F2%5F%2E000" FileRef.urlencodeasurl="/sites/heg/Lists/signup/2_.000" FileDirRef="/sites/heg/Lists/signup" Last_x0020_Modified="5/28/2012 11:15 AM" Created_x0020_Date="0;#2012-05-28 11:15:08" Created_x0020_Date.ifnew="" FSObjType="0" SortBehavior="0" PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" FileLeafRef="2_.000" FileLeafRef.Name="2_" FileLeafRef.Suffix="000" UniqueId="{E0BA736D-BE1E-486F-BBC3-A0CC6E6C8540}" SyncClientId="" ProgId="" ScopeId="{F73AF7C0-59A1-4A38-A1FF-D6600650485E}" HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type="" _EditMenuTableStart="2_.000" _EditMenuTableStart2="2" _EditMenuTableEnd="2" LinkFilenameNoMenu="2_.000" LinkFilename="2_.000" LinkFilename2="2_.000" DocIcon="" ServerUrl="/sites/heg/Lists/signup/2_.000" EncodedAbsUrl="https://sub.mydomain.co.uk/sites/heg/Lists/signup/2_.000" BaseName="2_" MetaInfo="" MetaInfo.="2;#" _Level="1" _Level.="1" _IsCurrentVersion="Yes" _IsCurrentVersion.value="1" ItemChildCount="0" FolderChildCount="0"></Row>
  </signup-list>
</dsQueryResponse>
```

Comment: From which xsl template are you calling the xpath? (i.e. `dvt_1.rowview`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Based on the data sample provided in the question update, I think this XPath should work for you:

```
count(/dsQueryResponse/signup-attendees/Rows/Row[@Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup_x00=current()/@ID])
```

This query means: in signup-attendees list, select all rows, having `Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup_x00` attribute of a row equal to ID attribute of the current element. Current element must point to a row of the events list, i.e. `/dsQueryResponse/signup-list/Rows/row`.

Haven't tested, but should work.

So your main mistake was that you pointed to wrong attribute. Basically, there was no "@Signup_ID_Lookup" attribute at all. Spaces in field title are replaced with `_x0020_` when SharePoint generates field internal name based on title.

Second point was that there are few attributes in DVWP data source for each lookup field:

1. **Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup** contains HTML with link, which is displayed to user.
2. **Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup.** contains lookup data in SharePoint format, id and title of the lookup item separated by ";#"
3. **Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup_x00** contains ID of lookup item
4. **Signup_x0020_ID_x0020_Lookup_x000** contains Title of lookup item

Comment: Thanks Andrey, this is similar to the second example I gave in my question which returns 4; 4; 4; I'm wondering if the problem might be that I'm in the wrong template to be trying to count the number of attributes with the sign_up_id equal to the original ID. Your thoughts?

Comment: Anyway, maybe I understand the question wrong or the data structure. If I was right, the query must succeed, there is no doubt. Could you find the root template (`match="/"`) and place code `<textarea cols="80" rows="6"><xsl:copy-of select="/" /></textarea>` there, and then update your question with the string you get in the textarea? This will allow me to come up with the precise answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Hope it helps this time. Warning, though: if the data your provided is correct, I'm afraid events Test01 and Test02 will both get only 1 attendee counted in. Please, examine the data closely: _Signup 01_ points to event _Test 02_, _Signup 02_ -> _Test 03_, and _Signup 04_ -> _Test 01_.

Comment: You are correct on all accounts, I removed the incorrect list item for the example to be able to squeeze in my update. Thank you for your response above, I however am still not getting what I would expect (when executed on the full data set) - the result is now 0; 0; 0; I must thank you for your persistance with my query.

Comment: Ooops, sorry. I've missed "Rows" in the query. Please, see the updated answer.

Comment: That has worked! Thank you. Annoyingly, this has probably worked all along if not for me not realising that the Formula UI on the ribbon in SharePoint Designer 2010 was not correctly interpreting Current(). In the result box it was showing 4; 4; 4;, when I pressed ok, it returned the correct values. When I have a better grasp of XSLT I shall not use the Formula UI!!! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Btw, a very interesting note about Formula UI, didn't know about this.

Comment: EXCELLENT Andrey, it worked for me. Thanks a Lot !!.

Comment: @Andrey 
can we do it in the same way to find out the number of distinct rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is a must customized approach.
Use the OOTB functionality.

Follow the steps:

1. Select your dataview webpart (in Sharepoint Designer).
2. Go to ribbon and select 'Filter'.
3. Group By : Event Id (Ascending/Descending)
4. Check the checkbox - 'Show Group Header'
5. Click on the button 'Advanced Sort Expression' and select the checkbox 'Show group totals'
6. Now you would be having your desired output.
7. In dvt_1.body comment the template call to rowview & groupheader0 or remove them: `<!-- <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowview/> -->`
8. In dvt_1.groupfooter0, modify the layout as per your wish.

(There would not be any need of custom coding. Also, steps 7 and 8 are optional.)

Comment: The option to Group/Ungroup is greyed out for me.